# react-native-collapsible close collapsible from any press

Tags: react-native, react-native-collapsible

I am using react-native-collapsible for a project. Everything working well but I would like the user to be able to close the collapsible by clicking anywhere on the screen when it is opened. On a desktop it would be easy with a !event.target match but since I am new to React Native (expo) I am a bit out of solution.
Thanks a lot, I pasted no code because I am currently using the Lorem example from the lib so won't be much useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can Make one useState variable and pass it into the property of
`collapsed={Your useState Veriable}` react-native-collapsible .
also make all the Design wrap into `TouchableOpacity` and it's onPress event to make it true.